# Sort a nested List on two elements

Tags: java, list, sorting, nested-lists, comparator

I have a *nested list*, named `outputToStore` whose contents are given below:

```
[[Final, 331, M, 22/03/2020 00:00:00], 
 [Initial, 335, M, 22/06/2022 00:00:00], 
 [Exception, 335, M, 22/05/2022 00:00:00], 
 [Final, 335, M, 20/06/2022 00:00:00], 
 [Keep, 335, M, 02/06/2022 11:00:00], 
 [Final, 335, M, 10/04/2022 02:00:00], 
 [Deleted, 335, M, 22/06/2022 15:55:10],
 [Exception, 335, M, 22/06/2022 15:55:09], 
 [Final, 335, M, 22/06/2022 15:56:00], 
 [Initial, 335, M, 11/06/2022 00:00:00]]
```

I need to sort this based on 2 conditions: The first is a custom order: *"Initial","Final","Deleted","Keep","Exception"* and then based on *datetime*.

I am able to do it, but not sure that this is the best way to do it.

*My code:*

```
List<String> definedOrder = Arrays.asList("Initial","Final","Deleted","Keep","Exception");
Collections.sort(outputToStore, Comparator.comparing(o -> Integer.valueOf(definedOrder.indexOf(o.get(0)))));
Collections.sort(outputToStore,( o1, o2)-> {
    // let your comparator look up your car's color in the custom order
    try {
        if(Integer.valueOf(definedOrder.indexOf(o1.get(0))).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(definedOrder.indexOf(o2.get(0))))==0){
            Date date1=simpleDateFormat.parse(o1.get(3));
            Date date2=simpleDateFormat.parse(o2.get(3));
            return date1.compareTo(date2);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
});
```

I'm getting the desired result:

```
[[Initial, 335, M, 11/06/2022 00:00:00],
 [Initial, 335, M, 22/06/2022 00:00:00],
 [Final, 331, M, 22/03/2020 00:00:00],
 [Final, 335, M, 10/04/2022 02:00:00],
 [Final, 335, M, 20/06/2022 00:00:00],
 [Final, 335, M, 22/06/2022 15:56:00],
 [Deleted, 335, M, 22/06/2022 15:55:10],
 [Keep, 335, M, 02/06/2022 11:00:00],
 [Exception, 335, M, 22/05/2022 00:00:00],
 [Exception, 335, M, 22/06/2022 15:55:09]]
```

But is there any better or concise way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use the Power of Objects

The way you're representing your data is inconvenient and error-prone.

It clearly has to be an **object** having attributes of appropriate types, and not a list of strings. It's misuse of collections

Using `String` as a type for numbers, dates, etc. doesn't give you any advantage. There's nothing you can do with string without parsing apart from printing on the console. Proper data-types give you access to their unique behavior that `String` can't offer you.

The first property, let's call it `status` might be an *enum*. *Enum* - is a special kind of class, they are very handy when you need to represent a limited set of values, and they have a *natural order*, that is the same as the order of the *enum-constants* (the order in which they have been declared).

And to represent date-time information we can use one of the Java 8 classes from `java.time` package. In the example below, I'll use `LocalDateTime` (class `Date` is legacy, avoid using it).

That how such a class might look like:

```
public class Foo {
    public enum Status {INITIAL, FINAL, DELETED, KEEP, EXCEPTION}
    
    private CountComponents.Foo.Status status;
    private int value1;
    private String value2;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
    
    // constructor, getters, etc.
}
```

#### Building Comparators with Java 8

In order to sort a list of `Foo` objects, we need to define a comparator.

For that, we can use static methods that were introduced in the `Comparator` interface with Java 8. We can chain these methods in a fluent way because each of them gives a comparator.

```
Comparator<Foo> byStatusByDate =
    Comparator.comparing(Foo::getStatus)
        .thenComparing(Foo::getDateTime);
```

**Note:** we need to define the sorting logic in a *single comparator*. Don't sort the data twice like you've done in your code, it causes unnecessary performance overhead.

To learn how to build comparators using Java-8 methods, have a look at [*this tutorial*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing).

And to sort a list of `Foo` objects, we can use method `List.sort()` which was introduced in Java 9 as a more fluent alternative to `Collections.sort()`:

```
List<Foo> foos = // initializing the list
    
foos.sort(byStatusByDate);
```

## Parsing the data

If data comes to you as a collection of strings, then you need to parse it.

For that we need to enhance `Foo` and its nested *enum* (the full code provided in the link below).

```
public static class Foo {
    public enum Status {
        INITIAL, FINAL, DELETED, KEEP, EXCEPTION;
        
        public static Status parse(String str) {
            return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(cons -> cons.name().equalsIgnoreCase(str))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow();
        }
    }
    
    private Status status;
    private int value1;
    private String value2;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
    
    public static Foo parse(List<String> strings, DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
        return new Foo(Status.parse(strings.get(0)),
            Integer.parseInt(strings.get(1)),
            strings.get(2),
            LocalDateTime.parse(strings.get(3), formatter));
    }
    
    // constructor, getters, etc.
}
```

**Note:** `SimpleDateFormat` class is legacy, the modern alternative is [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#method-summary).

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> strings = List.of(
        List.of("Final", "331", "M", "22/03/2020 00:00:00"),
        List.of("Initial", "335", "M", "22/06/2022 00:00:00"),
        List.of("Exception", "335", "M", "22/05/2022 00:00:00"),
        List.of("Final", "335", "M", "20/06/2022 00:00:00"),
        List.of("Keep", "335", "M", "02/06/2022 11:00:00"),
        List.of("Final", "335", "M", "10/04/2022 02:00:00"),
        List.of("Deleted", "335", "M", "22/06/2022 15:55:10"),
        List.of("Exception", "335", "M", "22/06/2022 15:55:09"),
        List.of("Final", "335", "M", "22/06/2022 15:56:00"),
        List.of("Initial", "335", "M", "11/06/2022 00:00:00")
    );

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    
    Comparator<Foo> byStatusByDate =
        Comparator.comparing(Foo::getStatus)
            .thenComparing(Foo::getDateTime);
    
    List<Foo> foos = strings.stream()           // Stream<List<String>>
        .map(list -> Foo.parse(list,formatter)) // Stream<Foo>
        .sorted(byStatusByDate)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());          // or .toList() for Java 16 +
    
    foos.forEach(System.out::println); // printing the result
}
```

*Output:*

```
Foo{status=INITIAL, value1=335, value2='M', dateTime=2022-06-11T00:00}
Foo{status=INITIAL, value1=335, value2='M', dateTime=2022-06-22T00:00}
Foo{status=FINAL, value1=331, value2='M', dateTime=2020-03-22T00:00}
Foo{status=FINAL, value1=335, value2='M', dateTime=2022-04-10T02:00}
Foo{status=FINAL, value1=335, value2='M', dateTime=2022-06-20T00:00}
Foo{status=FINAL, value1=335, value2='M', dateTime=2022-06-22T15:56}
Foo{status=DELETED, value1=335, value2='M', dateTime=2022-06-22T15:55:10}
Foo{status=KEEP, value1=335, value2='M', dateTime=2022-06-02T11:00}
Foo{status=EXCEPTION, value1=335, value2='M', dateTime=2022-05-22T00:00}
Foo{status=EXCEPTION, value1=335, value2='M', dateTime=2022-06-22T15:55:09}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/t3i)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static final List<String> definedOrder = List.of(
    "Initial","Final","Deleted","Keep","Exception");
static final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
record Rec(int key0, Date key1, List<String> row) {}

static Date parseDate(String input) {
    try {
        return simpleDateFormat.parse(input);
    } catch (ParseException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> outputToStore = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList("Final", "331", "M", "22/03/2020 00:00:00"), 
        Arrays.asList("Initial", "335", "M", "22/06/2022 00:00:00"), 
        Arrays.asList("Exception", "335", "M", "22/05/2022 00:00:00"), 
        Arrays.asList("Final", "335", "M", "20/06/2022 00:00:00"), 
        Arrays.asList("Keep", "335", "M", "02/06/2022 11:00:00"), 
        Arrays.asList("Final", "335", "M", "10/04/2022 02:00:00"), 
        Arrays.asList("Deleted", "335", "M", "22/06/2022 15:55:10"),
        Arrays.asList("Exception", "335", "M", "22/06/2022 15:55:09"), 
        Arrays.asList("Final", "335", "M", "22/06/2022 15:56:00"), 
        Arrays.asList("Initial", "335", "M", "11/06/2022 00:00:00")
    );

    List<List<String>> sorted = outputToStore.stream()
        .map(e -> new Rec(definedOrder.indexOf(e.get(0)), parseDate(e.get(3)), e))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Rec::key0).thenComparing(Rec::key1))
        .map(Rec::row)
        .toList();

    for (List<String> row : sorted)
        System.out.println(row);
}
```

output:

```
[Initial, 335, M, 11/06/2022 00:00:00]
[Initial, 335, M, 22/06/2022 00:00:00]
[Final, 335, M, 10/04/2022 02:00:00]
[Final, 335, M, 20/06/2022 00:00:00]
[Final, 331, M, 22/03/2020 00:00:00]
[Final, 335, M, 22/06/2022 15:56:00]
[Deleted, 335, M, 22/06/2022 15:55:10]
[Keep, 335, M, 02/06/2022 11:00:00]
[Exception, 335, M, 22/05/2022 00:00:00]
[Exception, 335, M, 22/06/2022 15:55:09]
```

Comment: Since Java 8 `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are considered to be legacy and *not* encouraged to be used. Classes from `java.time` package should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

A map might be better to use for the predefined order and use `LocalDateTime` to compare by date. But else your were on the right track; you could just chain `thenComparing` to your Comparator :

```
Map<String,Integer> definedOrder = Map.of(
        "Initial", 1, "Final", 2, "Deleted", 3, "Keep", 4, "Exception", 5);

final DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

outputToStore.sort(Comparator.comparing((List<String> list) -> definedOrder.get(list.get(0)))
        .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(list -> LocalDateTime.parse(list.get(3), df)))
);
```